# R: How to make a violin/box plot of the last (or any) data points in a time series?

Tags: ggplot2, plot

I have the following data frame, A, and would like to make a violin/box plot of the last data points (or any other selected) for all IDs in a time series, i.e. for time=90 the values for ID = 1...10 should be plotted.

```
A = data.frame(ID = rep(seq(1,5),each=10), 
               time = rep(seq(0,90,by = 10),5),
               value = rnorm(50))

   ID time        value
1   1    0  0.056152116
2   1   10  0.560673698
3   1   20 -0.240922725
4   1   30 -1.054686869
5   1   40 -0.734477812
6   1   50  1.123602646
7   1   60 -2.242830898
8   1   70 -0.818526167
9   1   80  1.476234401
10  1   90 -0.332324134
11  2    0 -1.486034438
12  2   10  0.222252053
13  2   20 -0.675720560
14  2   30 -3.144918043
15  2   40  3.058383376
16  2   50  0.978174555
17  2   60 -0.280927730
18  2   70 -0.188338714
19  2   80 -1.115583389
20  2   90  0.362044729
...
41  5    0  0.687402844
42  5   10 -1.127714642
43  5   20  0.117758547
44  5   30  0.507666153
45  5   40  0.205580300
46  5   50 -1.033018214
47  5   60 -1.906279605
48  5   70  0.117539035
49  5   80 -0.968888556
50  5   90  0.122049005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
set.seed(42)

A = data.frame(ID = rep(seq(1,5),each=10), 
               time = rep(seq(0,90,by = 10),5),
               value = rnorm(50))


library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

filter(A, time == 90) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>